# calling an iframe inside a js function

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, external-links

I'm trying to create an external link, that appears within the same site.

Here, If I click on a link it should display the contents of that link(external site) within our site. i.e., if my site is siteA and in that I place a link (to siteB) that will redirect to 'siteB' closing 'siteA'. I just want to avoid the situation besides I want to make the siteB to be opened within the siteA

My idea is when the link is opened, an iframe will be created and the external site will be opened within that Iframe.

```
 <a href="http://www.google.com" target="your_frame_name" onclick="executeOnClick()">Google</a>

 <script type="text/javascript">

   function executeOnClick(){
      <iframe name="your_frame_name" src="www.google.com" > </iframe>
             return true;
        }

       </script>
```

I wrote this code, but couldn't get what I expect. I tried to use button, but it's not working.

Is there any other way to fix my issue..

Comment: MOst of the answers are correct!! :P Choose wisely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No javascript is needed, use `target` attribute:

```
<a href="http://www.hopamchuan.com" target="iframe1">Load the page</a>

<iframe id="iframe1"> </iframe>
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kw8Qk/1/)

**IMPORTANT**: you cannot display http://google.com in iframes because of their `X-Frame-Options`. See: [The X-Frame-Options response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header)

Comment: What are you saying .. I ran google in your fiddle!!

Comment: Sorry, the label is 'Google' but the link is linked to http://hopamchuan.com. I have updated the fiddle.

Comment: Noo, I could get the result. There is no change with output, I hope this is not the good one (i mean what I want).

Answer (score 0):

```
function executeOnClick(){
      $('body').append('<iframe name="your_frame_name" src="www.google.com" height=200 width=200 > </iframe>');
             return true;
        }
```

try this

Comment: Even if Google.com allowed loading in an iframe, there's a big reason this code wouldn't work. It's related to the `src` element. The URL is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

The `iframe` markup should not be inside your `JavaScript` function. That does nothing except throwing an exception. Put the markup below your anchor and change its `src` on click:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="executeOnClick(this)">Google</a>
<iframe id="targetFrame"></iframe>

<script>
    function executeOnClick(target) {
        document.getElementById("targetFrame").src = target.src;
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

In fact you don't even need `JavaScript` to do this. You can use the `target` attribute of the anchor and set it to be the name of the frame you want to open the page in:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="targetFrame">Google</a>
<iframe name="targetFrame" id="targetFrame"></iframe>
```

Comment: I want the frame to appear only when we click "google" (href). the page should be empty with the only text google(href) and after a click the iframe should execute. if there is no click iframe shouldn't execute,

Answer (score 0):

Change to this:

```
onclick="executeOnClick(this); return false;"
```

and do this in your funcition:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function executeOnClick(elem){
      var frame = '<iframe name="your_frame_name" src="'+ elem.getAttribute('href') +'" > </iframe>';
      document.body.appendChild(frame); // <----append it here.
   }
</script>
```

---

In your onclick function you have to `return false;` to stop the default behaviour of an anchor to take you to the another page.

Comment: same issue dude, I want the link(href) to be opened within the same page. whatever u said is true but it takes me to a new tab and opens the link in that tab

Comment: Initially, the page should be empty with some header and a link (let it be google here). When the link is click, it should take me to that site and should show that site within the page i.e., below the header (so our site will be active and external link will be opened below the header)..

Answer (score 0):

please note that the google.com will not work with iframe

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="executeOnClick('http://www.google.com')">Google</a>
<iframe id="targetFrame"></iframe>

<script>
    function executeOnClick(src) {
       document.getElementById("targetFrame").src =src;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Neither do stackoverflow.com  :D

Answer (score -1):

```
 <iframe src="www.google.com" height="400" width="551" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" runat="server"></iframe>
```

Use runat attribute too. Hope this works.
If doesn't, what's the error?

Comment: no change, same problem (google site/or any) opens in a new tab. I want the link to be opened in the same page replacing the text.

Comment: first the page should be empty only showing the link. when the link is clicked an iframe should be appear erasing the link (href)